Postgres data deleted automatically in kubernetes cluster locally
I have setup a kubernetes cluster locally with a postgres databases using Docker. I always leave the cluster on pause overnight on my PC and no data is lost after turning on the PC. However, tonight the data of the database was fully deleted without any action on my side.
I check that the pods, pvc and pv didn't restart since the last time it was fully working.

If your pod hasn't restarted but you have lost the data, then its probably a different issue entirely likely from the underlying infrastructure and less of a Kubernetes side problem. Anything from the pod logs?

In my previous project, I had similar issues recurring every month or two where somehow the posgres database files got corrupted for no reason. My solution? Backup the database using pg_dump and have the restore process automated or at least scripted whenever the corruption happened ...
